# Why would one machine regularly be dropped from a Citrix server, while another remains connected?

Tags: router, citrix

Trying to connect to work from home via Citrix.

I get in ok for a minute then its say 'Connection interrupted' and attempts to reconnect again.  Then the whole cycle begins again.

I just got a new router billion router 7800VDOX

Anyone have any ideas on what I can do to sort this out? My internet connection is fine.

Thanks

Comment: Ok new information it works fine on my laptop but not on my big desktop PC with Win 7 64bit

Comment: Can you add the last ten lines of a wireshark trace of this connection -- a few normal packets, then where it goes wrong?

Comment: See this [Citrix Knowledge Center article](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX115648). See also [Citrix Troubleshooting Steps](http://www.asurionsupport.com/wah/support/citrix.html). Please comment.

Comment: Ping statistics for 74.125.237.5:
    Packets: Sent = 50087, Received = 50055, Lost = 32 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 19ms, Maximum = 703ms, Average = 38ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have lost packets, which would cause the Citrix server to drop the connection.

I would suggest first to check if the router's firmware has an update.
I found one for the [BiPAC 7800VDOX](http://au.billion.com/products/voip/firmware/bipac7800vdox.html) (is this your model?).
Be very careful, as such an update can brick your router.

If you are still having lost packets after that update, you could maybe try another router.

Question: Are you connected via wired or wireless?

Comment: At home both my laptop and PC go through the same router (laptop is wireless though). Laptop doesn't have a problem - PC does. Ill try the firmware update and report back